# Cómo corregir el error "1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Tags: mysql, sql, .net

En MySQL tengo 2 tablas, la tabla `ciudadano` esta relacionada con la otra `examen`; examen tiene el campo `examen.Cedula_Ciudadano` que viene de `ciudadano.Cedula`.

¿Cómo hago para actualizar desde ciudadano un registro y al mismo tiempo actualizarlo en examen? Porque me manda el error:

> ```
> error 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> ```

El código es el siguiente:

```
UPDATE 
    examen e 
    JOIN ciudadano c 
    on e.Cedula_Ciudadano=c.Cedula 
SET 
    e.Cedula_Ciudadano='s',
    c.Cedula='s'
WHERE 
    c.Cedula='222-301000-11023'
```

Comment: publica el código que estas trabajando, para ayudarte

Comment: UPDATE examen e JOIN ciudadano c on e.Cedula_Ciudadano=c.Cedula SET e.Cedula_Ciudadano='s',c.Cedula='s'
WHERE e.Cedula_Ciudadano='222-301000-11023'

Comment: Gracias por sus repuestas!!! lo arregle con las especificaciones al CONSTRAINT con update cascade

Comment: En si la solución es fácil, es más bien error humano, partiendo del supuesto que la transacción la realizas manualmente, lo que sucede es que el ID que quieres afectar no existe, razón por la cual te lanza el error 1452, dicho esto lo que debes de validar es el ID del ciudadano teniendo en cuenta que el ID de este debe ser auto incremental,créeme te ahorras muchos dolores de cabeza y según normas de diseño se debe seguir así, al menos si sigues las FORMAS NORMALES.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

En general, no es buena idea usar un campo que no es fijo a través del tiempo como llave primaria. Por ejemplo, en la tabla `Ciudadano`, sería una mejor implementación crear un campo auto-incrementable de la siguiente forma: `id_ciudadano INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`, y agregar la cédula como un valor más. De esta forma, el `id_ciudadano` nunca cambiaría, y podría ser una llave primaria perfecta, no teniendo que implementar algún artífice descrito en esta o las demás respuestas.

### Posible solución

El error `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` aparece cuando:

- intentas eliminar un registro del que se tiene dependencia en otra tabla.
- intentas agregar un registro con una dependencia no existente en otra tabla.

Por lo que estás diciendo, supongo que intentas cambiar la cédula del ciudadano. Muy probablemente dicho ciudadano ya tiene registrado un examen en la correspondiente tabla, y por ello te lanza el error.

Puedes hacer dos cosas:

1. Eliminar las dependencias de la tabla referida y proceder a actualizar el campo.
2. Agregar especificaciones al `CONSTRAINT`de tu llave foránea.

### Eliminar las dependencias referidas

Supongamos que tenemos al ciudadano con cédula `1234`, y dicho usuario tiene dos exámenes en la tabla `examen`. Todo lo que tendrías que hacer es ejecutar esta instrucción:

```
DELETE FROM examen WHERE Cedula_Ciudadano = 1234;
```

Si lo que quieres es mantener los exámenes de dicho ciudadano, guarda los datos del exámen e insértalos después con la nueva cédula. Si estás haciéndolo desde un script, es una tarea fácil. Si lo haces desde un servicio programado, la mayoría de lenguajes proveen de funciones para realizar tareas de inserts bastante fácil.

### Agreagar especificaciones al CONSTRAINT

Al momento de crear una llave foránea, en MySQL por default se agregan las siguientes especificaciones:

```
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Lo único que hay que hacer es alterar esas configuraciones para que al momento de cambiar la cédula del ciudadano, se cambie también las referencias en los exámenes. **Punto negativo**: Sólo puede realizarse en el momento de crear la tabla, por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE examen (
    Cedula_Ciudadano INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Ciudadano(Cedula) ON UPDATE CASCADE 
);
```

Cuando la tabla ha sido creada y ya tiene datos, se tendría que eliminar y recrear ([ver esta respuesta para más información](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1572051/2835257))

Comment: Gracias me sirvió lo del Update cascade

Comment: Hola @fredmar si te sirvió puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada

Comment: @alejandro00 no hay que añadir nada a la respuesta en su lugar deja un comentario

Answer (score 1):

tuve el mismo error y lo pude corregir con...

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

tambien puedes usar...

```
SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

pero es mas seguro la pirmera opcion ya que solo esta activo mientras dura la sesion

Fuentes: [ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55372574/15308734)