# Dudas en la creación de Base de datos en Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

Tengo una duda con respecto a la creación de una base de datos en workbench, la base de datos a crear es referente a registros de Embarcaciones..

Este consistiría en llevar un control de datos de embarcaciones que se encuentra en una marina. Esta marina cuenta con 3 áreas, las cuales son: Muelles, Patio de Trabajo (esta área es solo para realizar mantenimiento de embarcaciones) y el Patio de Larga Estadía (denominado también Estacionamiento en Seco, esta área es para estacionar el barco en tierra)...

La siguiente base de datos contendra tablas para almacenar los datos de propietarios, embarcaciones, capitanes y los movimientos realizados por la embarcaciones (estos movimientos se originan cuando una embarcación ubicada en muelle solicita un servicio de varado en el área de Patio de Trabajo para realizar mantenimiento  o para estacionar en el área de Patio de Larga Estadía).

Los siguientes datos a almacenar en cada tabla son los siguientes:

```
- Propietario:                                  
*Cédula, rif o pasaporte
*Nombre
*Apellido
*Nacionalidad
*Dirección
*Teléfono
*Correo

-Embarcaciones
*Matricula
*Fecha de entrada de la embarcación a las instalaciones de la marina
*Nombre de Embarcación
*Tipo de embarcación (Y) en caso de ser yate, (C) en caso de ser catamarán y (V) en caso de ser velero.
*Bandera
*Pies 
*Manga 
*Calado
*UAB (peso del barco)  
*Permiso de estadía (este campo almacenaría la fecha de hasta cuando tiene permiso una embarcación para estar dentro del país)(Aplica solo para embarcaciones extranjeras)
*Licencia de Navegación (este campo almacenaría la fecha de vencimiento del permiso de navegabilidad de una embarcación (solo aplica para embarcaciones venezolanas)
*Certificado de Radio (este campo almacenaría la fecha de vencimiento del permiso de radio de la embarcación)
*Seguro (este campo almacenaría la fecha de vencimiento del seguro de responsabilidad civil de una embarcación)
*Tipo de requerimiento (tipo de trabajo a realizar en la embarcación)

-Capitán
*Cédula o num de pasaporte
*Nombre
*Apellido
*Dirección
*Telefono
*Correo
*Patrón (este campo almacenaría la fecha de vencimiento del permiso de conducir embarcaciones de un capitán)

-Movimientos de embarcaciones
*Ubicación del barco (si esta en el muelle, patio de trabajo o el patio de larga estadía)
*Fechas de movimientos realizados (este campo almacenaría las fechas de los movimientos realizados por las embarcaciones) por ejemplo el día 03 de diciembre la embarcación Atlantis pasó del muelle al patio de trabajo para realizar mantenimiento.
```

A continuación les muestro como lo estaba haciendo en workbench,

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema TMO
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema TMO
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `TMO` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `TMO` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `TMO`.`Emb_movimiento`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TMO`.`Emb_movimiento` (
  `fecha_mov` DATE NOT NULL,
  `ubicacion_emb` CHAR(4) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fecha_mov`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `TMO`.`Embarcacion`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TMO`.`Embarcacion` (
  `matricula` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  `fentradaEmb` DATE NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  `bandera` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `pies` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
  `manga` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
  `calado` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
  `uab` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
  `permiso_de_estadia` DATE NULL,
  `lic_de_nav` DATE NULL,
  `cert_de_radio` DATE NULL,
  `seguro` DATE NULL,
  `tipo_de_requer` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `Emb_movimiento_fecha_mov` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`matricula`, `Emb_movimiento_fecha_mov`),
  INDEX `fk_Embarcacion_Emb_movimiento1_idx` (`Emb_movimiento_fecha_mov` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Embarcacion_Emb_movimiento1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Emb_movimiento_fecha_mov`)
    REFERENCES `TMO`.`Emb_movimiento` (`fecha_mov`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `TMO`.`Propietario`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TMO`.`Propietario` (
  `idPropietarios` INT NOT NULL,
  `cedulo_rif_pasp` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `apellido` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `nacionalidad` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `telefono` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `correo` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `Embarcacion_matricula` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPropietarios`),
  INDEX `fk_Propietario_Embarcacion_idx` (`Embarcacion_matricula` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Propietario_Embarcacion`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Embarcacion_matricula`)
    REFERENCES `TMO`.`Embarcacion` (`matricula`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `TMO`.`Capitan`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TMO`.`Capitan` (
  `idCapitan` INT NOT NULL,
  `cedula_pasp` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `apellido` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `telefono` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `correo` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `patron` DATE NULL,
  `Embarcacion_matricula` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCapitan`),
  INDEX `fk_Capitan_Embarcacion1_idx` (`Embarcacion_matricula` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Capitan_Embarcacion1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Embarcacion_matricula`)
    REFERENCES `TMO`.`Embarcacion` (`matricula`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Luego de hacer las relaciones y tratar de insertar datos en la tabla de capitán me aparece el siguiente error:

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`tmo`.`capitan`, CONSTRAINT
>   `fk_Capitan_Embarcacion1` FOREIGN KEY (`Embarcacion_matricula`)
>   REFERENCES `embarcacion` (`matricula`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE
>   NO ACTION).

Agradecería su ayuda de antemano, soy nueva en esto y me gustaría solucionar dicho problema y poder finalizar la base de datos como proyecto personal.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. El error indica que en la inserción se intenta agregar una matrícula no existente en `embarcacion`.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Cómo corregir el error "1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73103/c%c3%b3mo-corregir-el-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-co) . Ver también [muchas otras preguntas (más de 30)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+add+or+update+a+child+row) sobre el mismo tema.

Comment: Hola Raquel te invito a hacer el [tour] para ganar medallas, quisiera comentarte que [workbench](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench) no es un motor de base de datos , es un gestor que de manera visual realiza operaciones a MySQL , tu error significa que estas haciendo un delete a la tabla , y esta tiene relaciones, MySQL para evitar romper tu esquema no te deja

Comment: ¿En qué instrucción falla exactamente?

Answer (score 0):

¿Cuál es la inserción que falla? Porque ese error indica que el problema está en cómo estás insertando los datos, no en la estructura.

Si hay una FOREIGN KEY de la tabla `Capitán` a la tabla `Embarcación`, **primero** tiene que haber registros en la tabla `Embarcación` para poder insertar luego en la tabla `Capitán` y que el valor en el campo `Embarcacion_matricula` (la que está asignada a cada capitán) exista. De eso se trata la FOREIGN KEY.

Ejemplo:

Primero iría

```
INSERT INTO 
Embarcacion(matricula, fentradaEmb, nombre, tipo, bandera, pies, manga, calado, uab, permiso_de_estadia, lic_de_nav, cert_de_radio, seguro, tipo_de_requer, Emb_movimiento_fecha_mov) 
VALUES
('MATRICULA1', ...<el resto de campos>);
```

y luego iría

```
INSERT INTO Capitan(idCapitan, cedula_pasp, nombre, apellido, direccion, telefono, correo, patron, Embarcacion_matricula) 
VALUES(1, 'PASP1', 'Nombre', 'Apellido', 'Calle Falsa 123', '1234567', 'capitan@sea.com', '2008-7-04', 'MATRICULA1')
```

¡El orden importa al insertar y borrar en tablas con FOREIGN KEYS!

Comment: Tienes suficiente reputación para comentar, ¿por qué usas el área de respuestas para algo que más bien debería ser un comentario aclaratorio?

Comment: @A.Cedano porque, aunque a la pregunta le falta información, la solución a la misma es lo que le indico que debe hacer. No aclara sino que responde. Gracias por revisar.

Comment: Puede que una vez corregido ese error, surjan otros parecidos. Ante preguntas como estas no es tan simple dar una respuesta definitiva.

Comment: Pues si sale otro error, es otra pregunta. El mensaje de error es claro.

Comment: No necesariamente. Puede ser un mismo `Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row`... No puede sugerirse una pregunta por cada columna fallida. Y si son todos errores de ese tipo, puede que [la pregunta sea considerada duplicada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/73103/29967).

Comment: No espero que seamos estrictos en una pregunta por columna fallida. Incluso en el sitio original la cosa es más bien flexible, el OP comenta la respuesta, edita la pregunta si hay información adicional y uno edita la respuesta acorde con ello. Si cambia totalmente el problema, es en otra capa o componente, es otra pregunta totalmente diferente. Acabo de eliminar una respuesta que sí era claramente un comentario, esta la dejo a criterio de los moderadores. ¡Buen día!

Comment: Mi intención no es fastidiar tu respuesta. Hay aquí ya al menos 34 preguntas sobre ese mismo tema. Creo que es importante cuidar la limpieza del sitio evitando responder a preguntas que son claras candidatas a duplicadas.