# ¿Saben por qué me marca ERROR?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Tengo tres tablas artículos, facturas y detalles_factura.
La tabla de detalles contiene como `FOREIGN KEY` id_facturas y id_artículos y otro campo que es un `FLOAT`.

Con un Store Procedure quiero agregar un nuevo registro a la tabla de detalles_factura por ejemplo:

`call ventas_x1.sp_alta_detalles_factura(5, 32, 30);`

Previamente revise que los registros existieran en las tablas principales (en la imagen se pude ver que id 32 si existe en la tabla de artículos).
No tengo idea de porque me lanza ese error, si alguien me lo pudiera explicar lo agradecería.

**Anexo el código del Procedure**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_alta_detalles_factura`(in id_fact2 int, in id_art2 int, in can_ar float)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO detalles_factura VALUES (id_factura2, id_articulo2, cant_art);
END
```

**Error que me marca MySQL Workbench**

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ventas_x1`.`detalles_factura`, CONSTRAINT `fk_id_articulo2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_articulo2`) REFERENCES `articulos` (`id_articulo`))
```

[image: IMAGEN DEL ERROR]

Comment: Es extraño porque al agregar los datos con un `INSERT` funciona sin problemas.

Comment: Seria mejor si pones el codigo de tu Procedure para poder analizarlo y ademas el error completo, por que ahi en lo que se alcanza a leer te esta diciendo que estas haciendo una insercion o actualizacion invalida o que te faltan elementos.

Comment: @ivan
Ya agregue el código.

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas rapida, insegura y **QUE NO TE RECOMIENDO** es quitando el modo seguro de las consultas

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_alta_detalles_factura`(in id_fact2 int, in id_art2 int, in can_ar float)
BEGIN
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
    INSERT INTO detalles_factura VALUES (id_factura2, id_articulo2, cant_art);
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
END
```

Escencialmente lo que te esta diciendo es que quieres insertar un dato que **NO** tiene relacion, mas especificamente

De la tabla `detalles_factura` quieres poner el valor `id_articulo2` sin que este exista en la tabla referenciada `articulos.id_articulos`

> Posible solución
>       El error Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails aparece cuando intentas eliminar un registro del que se tiene dependencia en otra tabla, o cuando intentas agregar un registro con una dependencia no existente en otra tabla.

...

> 1. Eliminar las dependencias de la tabla referida y proceder a actualizar
>      el campo.
> 2. Agregar especificaciones al CONSTRAINTde tu llave foránea.

En lo personal yo revisaria que tu llave foranea tenga activo el `on update cascade`

Cuentame si te ayudo mi respuesta, si no para buscar juntos una solucion.

Referencia [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73103/c%C3%B3mo-corregir-el-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-co)

Puedes leer el articulo original [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659691/error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails) o la fuente oficial [aca](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Sin embargo no es recomendable, pero es necesario que lo conozcas para ocasiones en las que debas hacer modificaciones rapidas

Comment: Active el ON UPDATE CASCADE pero aun así sigue saliendo el error.

Comment: Intenta hacer el insert sin el procedure, si funciona entonces es con la configuracion de tu workbench si no funciona entonces es el id que no es correcto

Comment: Ya lo había probado antes y con un insert normal si funciona bien.