# Cómo corregir el error “1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails”

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hola estoy creando una tabla en mi base de datos pero no me permite ingresar valores les comparto como lo hice

```
CREATE TABLE `profesores_materias` (
`id_profesor` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_carrera` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_materia` int(11) NOT NULL,
`fecha` date NOT NULL,
`operador` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_profesor`,`id_carrera`,`id_materia`),
KEY `id_profesor` (`id_profesor`,`id_carrera`,`id_materia`),
KEY `id_materia` (`id_materia`),
KEY `id_carrera` (`id_carrera`),
CONSTRAINT `profesores_materias_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_profesor`) REFERENCES `profesores` 
(`id_profesor`),
CONSTRAINT `profesores_materias_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_materia`) REFERENCES `materias` 
(`id_materia`),
CONSTRAINT `profesores_materias_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_carrera`) REFERENCES `carreras` 
(`id_carrera`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Esta es la información que necesito cargar en la tabla pero me da error 1452:

```
INSERT INTO `profesores_materias` (`id_profesor`, `id_carrera`, `id_materia`, `fecha`, `operador`) 
VALUES
(2, 1, 1, '0000-00-00', ''),
(2, 1, 4, '0000-00-00', ''),
(2, 1, 20, '0000-00-00', ''),
(2, 1, 7, '0000-00-00', ''),
```

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Existe en la tabla profesores el id 2? Existe en la tabla materias el id 1? Existen en la tabla carreras los ids 1,4,7 y 20?

Comment: Si estan todos los id

Comment: @NicoPatrignani no es que no te creamos, pero es que el error está diciendo que uno de esos valores no está. O no hay carrera con ese id_carrera, o no hay materia con ese id_materia, o no hay profesor con ese id_profesor. Y tienes que crearlos ANTES de hacer este insert que nos muestras.

Comment: Si estaba mal el nº de id_profesor muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cómo corregir el error "1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73103/c%c3%b3mo-corregir-el-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-co)