# JDBC JAVA: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Esta es mi modelo ER de mi BBDD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me sale el error que está en el título al insertar datos en FrutasTicket y Ticket.
He probado por cambiar el orden(crear primero el ticket de la compra y crear primero el id de FrutasTicket), pero sigue sin funcionarme. Me sale un error y supongo que es porque la foránea no existe. No sé como insertar datos con la foránea vacía.

Comment: ¿Leíste [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/73103)? Además, muestra la estructura de tus tablas _como texto, con formato_ y la forma en la que intentas insertar datos (es decir: el código en donde intentas hacer el `INSERT`).

Comment: Ingresa primero las que no tienen FK, como Fruta y Persona luego continuas con las que tienen FK como ticket y Frutas ticket , dependiendo de cual es la de menor preponderancia.