# No puedo agregar una llave foranea a una tabla ya creada

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

Tengo una tabla fichas con un campo codigo_ficha dicho campo es UNIQUE, tambien tengo una tabla aprendices con un campo codigo_ficha el cual es referenciado de la tabla fichas. El error esta en que la tabla aprendices ya la tenia creada pero se me olvido agregar esa llave foranea lo estoy intentando hacer asi:

```
ALTER TABLE aprendices ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_ficha_aprendiz` FOREIGN KEY (codigo_ficha) REFERENCES aprendices(codigo_ficha);
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: Este es el error]

le estaría agradecido a quien me pueda ayudar a solucionar el error. Nose si tenga solucion o si deba volver a crear las tablas.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cómo corregir el error "1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73103/c%c3%b3mo-corregir-el-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-co)

Comment: Debes eliminar primero el campo codigo_ficha de la tabla de aprendices y luego crear la relación. Te esta indicando que ya existe una columna en aprendices con ese nombre.